# write test unit class to delete records from custom object list

Tags: apex

What I want to achieve is this: if account_setup request is rejected, the trigger will remove the record from the custom object account_setup__c
thanks for your help

this is my trigger:

```
trigger Delete_Rejected_Trigger on Account_Setup__c (After insert, After update){ 

     Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Account_Setup__c.status__c.getDescribe();
     List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = F.getPicklistValues();

        for (Account_Setup__c B : Trigger.new) { 
           Account ac = new Account();
            if(B.status__c == 'Approved'){  

              ac.Name = B.Name;

             insert ac;
          }
          Else if (B.status__c == 'Rejected'){ 

              Account_Setup__c R = [select Name,status__c
                                      From Account_Setup__c
                                      Where Status__c ='Rejected'];

              Delete R;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure about the test unit class, this is what I came up with

```
@isTest
public class Delete_Rejected_class{

// Status of 'Approved'
static testMethod void approved() {

    Account_Setup__c B = new Account_Setup__c();

    B.status__c = 'Approved';
    B.Name = 'Name' ;

    insert B;
 }
 static testMethod void rejected() {

    Account_Setup__c B = new Account_Setup__c();
    B.status__c = 'Rejected';
    Delete B;                         
}
}
```

the test method failed, giving me an error.

Comment: On another note your trigger isn't bulkified even the slightest.. may want to address that.  What was the error?

Comment: testmethod rejected() won't even trigger the 'delete_rejected_trigger` as that executes only on insert/update events, not delete events. And your testmethods don't do asserts to see if the trigger even did what it was supposed to do

Comment: Hi @kamal ,Do you want delete current record if status is "Rejected" right?,@EricSSH is specified the trigger is not handled bulkupload.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following code trigger is bulkified and also I have written the test class. I thought if status is 'Rejected' then trigger can DELETE the current record right?. Let me know if you have any doubt.

**Apex Trigger:**

```
trigger Delete_Rejected_Trigger on Account_Setup__c (After insert, After update)
{
    LIST<Account_Setup__c> deleteAcc = NEW LIST<Account_Setup__c>()
    LIST<Account> newAcc =  NEW LIST<Account>();
    FOR(Account_Setup__c B : [SELECT Id,Name,status__c FROM Account_Setup__c WHERE Id IN : Trigger.NEW AND status__c =: 'Approved' OR status__c =: 'Rejected']) 
    {           
                IF(B.status__c == 'Approved')
        {
            Account ac = new Account();
            ac.Name = B.Name;
            newAcc.add(ac);
        }
        ELSE IF(B.status__c == 'Rejected')
        {
            deleteAcc.add(B);
        }
    }
    IF(newAcc.SIZE() != 0)
        INSERT newAcc;
    IF(deleteAcc.SIZE() != 0)
        DELETE deleteAcc;

}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData = TRUE)
PUBLIC class Delete_Rejected_class
{
    static testMethod void myTestMethod()
        {
        Account_Setup__c B = NEW Account_Setup__c();
        B.status__c = 'Approved';
        B.Name = 'Name' ;
        INSERT B;
        Account_Setup__c B1 = NEW Account_Setup__c();
        B1.status__c = 'Rejected';
        B1.Name = 'Name1' ;
        INSERT B1;

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Ramesh, when I run on your test class, I get this error message "System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Delete_Rejected_Test: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Account_Setup__c.Name

Trigger.Delete_Rejected_Test: line 14, column 1: []

Comment: Hi Kamal,In select query I have  missing the filed called Name.I have edited my code.Can you please check and let me know.